# Custom formatters not registered - ConversionNotSupportedException : Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a custom formatter `@Component class DebitCardNumberFormatter implements Formatter<DebitCardNumber>{...}` I have added this formatter to the `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` by

```
<bean id="formattingConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="formatters">
            <set>
                <ref bean="debitCardNumberFormatter"/>
            </set>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Now when I explicitly run the following code, it works correctly and the string becomes DebitCardNumber,

```
DebitCardNumber debitCardNumber=formattingConversionService.convert("1234-3242
 -4533-3432",DebitCardNumber.class);
```

But if I try to inject a DebitCardNumber in another bean with a string value,

```
<bean id="cardDetails" class="com.amudhan.springcore.formatter.CardDetails">
        <property name="debitCardNumber" value="1234-3242-4533-3432"></property>
</bean>
```

The container throws ConversionNotSupportedException.

```
 org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.amudhan.springcore.formatter.DebitCardNumber] for property 'debitCardNumber'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.amudhan.springcore.formatter.DebitCardNumber] for property 'debitCardNumber': no matching editors or conversion strategy found`enter code here`
```

- I am reading the Spring documentation and practicing the APIs. What
  am I missing here ?
- Previously when I created 'Converter's, I used 'converters' property
  of `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` to add that    converter and use it
  automatically.
- In the same way I have tried adding the formatter by using the
  'formatters' property of `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean`.  Is
  there anything that I fundamentally missing ? Or Is my understanding
  of Formatters is plain wrong ?
- If It throws exception when I use spring to debitCardNumber it in the applicationContext, how come it is working correctly when I call the convert method explicitly from the app ? Even the beans are correctly created when I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to register your custom formatter

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
 <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
   <property name="formatters">
    <set>
        <ref bean="debitCardNumberFormatter"/>
    </set>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

**Update**

Alright after looking little deeper into the code. So spring is looking for conversion service bean in your application context with id "conversionService" in Abstract bean factory so it can use that to parse your bean instead of property editors(before Spring 3.0).

So now why it worked with converters but not formatters because your id name for custom formatter didn't match with the id("conversionService") spring is looking for.

Any other name for id it will not work and so it's not a problem between choosing converter or formatter.

Hope this helps.

This example with formatter should work.

```
 <bean id="conversionService"
          class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="formatters">
            <set>
                <ref bean="debitCardNumberFormatter"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Yes. But why it is not working in the way I have done when converters worked just fine ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Everything the same as in the above given XML configuration except, instead of "FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean", now I have "ConversionServiceFactoryBean" with converters property instead of formatters property. I injected a custom converter instead of a formatter as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: :Thank you. Your update helped and it worked. But I did not understand how. Why does the name of the factory bean matters here ? Because changing the factory bean name to conversionService as you have mentioned, from the formattingConversionService worked correctly. Does that mean the factory object creates beans using its own name ? If that is the specification, then how come Spring is not looking for a bean matching that of the factory bean, instead, by default looking for a bean named conversionService ?

Comment: No problem. There is only a singleton instance of conversion service per application context which can be conversion service factory for converters only and formatter conversion factory for both converters and formatters. So by using id conversion service for above factories, you're providing your own implementation of factory which spring will use to convert your string property values to object instead of property editors when resolving beans attributes. For all other purposes, you can autowire these beans in to your applications. Hope this helps.